# How to use dijit/Textarea validation (Dojo 1.9)?

Tags: validation, textarea, dojo, dojo-1.9

I have textarea which is required field. I've found [post suggesting that Dojo doesn't have validation for Textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072173/dojo-validation-of-a-textarea), but in Dojo 1.9, there's an argument 'required'.

I've done the following:

```javascript
new Textarea({required:true, value:""}, query('[name=description]')[0])
```

but the effect isn't what I've expected. The texarea has red border always, even if the field wasn't focused (as opposite to, for example, ValidationTextBox). But when I call:

```javascript
form.validate()
```

the validation is passed even if the texarea is empty.

Is it possible to get Textare behave the same as in ValidationTextBox, or as for now, the validation for that component is not yet ready and I'd have to write custom version (as in linked post) or wait for next Dojo?

Comment: I don't think that the validation of a textarea is possible with the default validation functionality. After all the value of the textare is in its inner HTML, and the values of other inputs are helf in the value attribute.

Comment: Some examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072173/dojo-validation-of-a-textarea)

Comment: @xyu yes, this is custom code, but I've asked how looks the status of the required in Textarea in Dojo 1.9? Is it still 'in development', or that behaviour is the by-design option? It's not consistent with other controls, therefore my doubt if it really a final version of code.

Comment: Check the [API](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dijit/form/Textarea). It doesn't look like `required` is a property of `Textarea`, so it is likely they do not fully support it.

Comment: Yup it's not consistent with the other input controls. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've done it using mixin of SimpleTextArea and ValidationTextArea:

```javascript
define(["dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/_base/lang", "dijit/form/SimpleTextarea", "dijit/form/ValidationTextBox"],
function(declare, lang, SimpleTextarea, ValidationTextBox) {

  return declare('dijit.form.ValidationTextArea', [SimpleTextarea, ValidationTextBox], {
    constructor: function(params){
      this.constraints = {};
      this.baseClass += ' dijitValidationTextArea';
    },    
    templateString: "<textarea ${!nameAttrSetting} data-dojo-attach-point='focusNode,containerNode,textbox' autocomplete='off'></textarea>"
  })
})
```

See also my answer in [Dojo validation of a textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19493524/531954)

Comment: how to include this declaration in a .js that already has a dojo define function, and use it in the same file?

Answer (score 1):

The power of Dojo lies in extending it with ease. If you really need the `required` functionality, then implement it. If you design it well, there should be no problem if it actually gets implemented in a new release of Dojo.

If you really want to know if such a feature exists or is in development I suggest looking at http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org. Besides, you can always contribute to the code, that's what open source is meant for.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add to the answer of *Donaudampfschifffreizeitfahrt*

instead of "this.baseClass += ' dijitValidationTextArea';"

I would do

```
this.baseClass = this.baseClass.replace('dijitTextBox', 'dijitValidationTextArea');
```

because

• we do not need the TextBox class if we have got a textarea mixin

• ! the "rows" parameter is mixed in but not fired/styled if the TextBox class is present ...