# PlaceHolder attribute no working for mixin of SimpleTextarea and ValidationTextBox

Tags: javascript, dojo

Hi I used an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19317258/how-to-use-dijit-textarea-validation-dojo-1-9) here on Stack Overflow to create a custom ValidationTextArea widget.  The problem I'm having is that the new custom widget doesnt display the `placeHolder`attribute.

The code for the custom widget is:

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/_base/lang", "dijit/form/SimpleTextarea", "dijit/form/ValidationTextBox"],
function (declare, lang, SimpleTextarea, ValidationTextBox) {

        return declare('dijit.form.ValidationTextArea', [SimpleTextarea, ValidationTextBox], {
            constructor: function (params) {
                this.constraints = {};
                this.baseClass += ' dijitValidationTextArea';
            },
            templateString: "<textarea ${!nameAttrSetting} data-dojo-attach-point='focusNode,containerNode,textbox' autocomplete='off'></textarea>"
        })
    })
```

and the markup for my widget is:

```
<textarea data-dojo-type="Scripts/ValidationTextArea"
                                  data-dojo-attach-point="taProjectDescription" style="width:425px; height:75px"
                                  required='true'
                                  placeHolder="max 3000 characters"
                                  data-dojo-props="trim:true,maxLength:'3000'"></textarea>
```

is there something I need to add to the custom widget code to get it to display placeHolder?  I'm viewing this on chrome

Thanks

Comment: The other thing I've noticed is that the widget considers return characters invalid.  Any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the place holder to your new template..

```
templateString:"<textarea ${!nameAttrSetting} 
  data-dojo-attach-point='focusNode,containerNode,textbox' 
  autocomplete='off' 
  placeHolder='${placeHolder}'>
  </textarea>"
```