# Return character is invalid for mixin of SimpleText Area and Validiation TextBox

Tags: javascript, dojo

I used an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19317258/how-to-use-dijit-textarea-validation-dojo-1-9) on Stack Overflow to create a custom Validation TextArea widget.  The issue I'm having is that the widget wont accept returns as valid characters.  Is there anything I can do to allow returns?  The control shows a red invalid indicator and a message the 'value entered is not valid' whenever a return is entered in the widget.  The code I'm using is below:

Custom Widget:

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/_base/lang", "dijit/form/SimpleTextarea", "dijit/form/ValidationTextBox"],
function (declare, lang, SimpleTextarea, ValidationTextBox) {

        return declare('dijit.form.ValidationTextArea', [SimpleTextarea, ValidationTextBox], {
            constructor: function (params) {
                this.constraints = {};
                this.baseClass += ' dijitValidationTextArea';
            },
            templateString: "<textarea ${!nameAttrSetting} data-dojo-attach-point='focusNode,containerNode,textbox' autocomplete='off' placeHolder='${placeHolder}'></textarea>"
        })
    })
```

Markup:

```
<textarea data-dojo-type="Scripts/ValidationTextArea"
                                  data-dojo-attach-point="taGoalsObjectives" style="width:425px; height:75px"
                                  required='true'
                                  placeHolder="max 2000 characters"
                                  data-dojo-props="trim:true,maxLength:'2000'"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

found the answer here on StackOverflow on this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072173/dojo-validation-of-a-textarea).  Added part of the solution provided by techscreen below the template string in the widget:

```
pattern: "[\\S\\s]+", /* Match not-whitepsace or whitespace. Default pattern for ValidationTextBox is .* which does not match new line characters */
```